# Series Expansion at n=infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Look at these two:

$$a_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\dfrac1{k(k-1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\dfrac1{k-1}-\dfrac1k\right]=1-\dfrac1n<1. \\ \ \\ a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac1{k!}=2+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac1{k!}\leq2+\sum_{k=2}^n\dfrac1{k(k-1)}=3-\dfrac1n<3.$$

Could anyone please explain me, how I can get to the series expansion on the right? So far, the stuff in the middle doesn't help me.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which part are you confused about?

Comment: Telescoping series?

Comment: In general, I don't understand how this works. I don't understand the above written solution.

Comment: Your $a_n$ are different, I'm lost. The first one is just cancelling terms two by two so you have the first and last left. The second is the same using partial fractions to link them.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k} = \frac{k}{k(k-1)} - \frac{k-1}{k(k-1)} = \frac{k-(k-1)}{k(k-1)} = \frac{1}{k(k-1)}.$$

The second sum should start at $k= 2$. Then we have

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k-1} - \sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{1} + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{n}.$$

In the second line, we use the fact that for $k \geq 2$, $k! \geq k(k-1)$ so $$\frac{1}{k!} \leq \frac{1}{k(k-1)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=2}^{n} \left[\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right]&=\sum_{k=2}^n \left[\frac{1}{k-1}\right]- \sum_{k=2}^n \left[\frac{1}{k}\right]\\
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&=1-\frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**1st part**

Take a look at the first bracket:

$\sum[\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac1k]$.

> First of all there is a typo there. This sum is from **k=2** until k=n

For k=2, it's value is $\frac11-\frac12$

For k=3, it's value is $\frac12-\frac13$

For k=4, it's value is $\frac13-\frac14$

...

For k=n, it's value is $\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n$.

If you add all thes values, you get most terms cancelled out and the result is $1-\frac1n$

**2nd part**
Here you just have to notice that $k!>k(k-1)$.

This is true because k!=1*2*3*....*(k-1)*k>1*1*1*....*(k-1)*k=(k-1)*k

So $\frac1{k!}<\frac1{k(k-1)}$.

From the 1st part, you know that this sum you know that equals $1-\frac1n$